# Color highlight stdout of a debugged/launched process in vscode

Tags: windows, terminal, visual-studio-code, highlighting

I am using VSCode as a main IDE. When I'm launching (or debugging) my developed software, which is usually a console application *(be it either, c++, java, or whatever)* I'd like to see its stdout coloured without actually having to implement it in the software itself.

So I'm looking for a way to be able to colourize lines in the terminal based on some pattern or regex. Eg. if it finds the word "ERROR", change the whole line to red.
Some examples in other IDEs:
https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/grep-console
https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7125-grep-console

But obviously, I'd like to use something similar in VSCode, not just "change IDE, problem solved".

Not sure whether it can be a VSCode feature/plugin or if it's a new terminal that must be set to VSCode as default, but I hope my goal is clear.

Comment: Cross-site dup. See [VSCode extension: How to render colored output in output channel?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55524643/11107541). Also: [How can I get colored output in VS Code output window?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57940666/11107541)

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong but in the "output" pane I can't see the stdout of the software I'm trying to run/debug. So this is hardly a solution for me